# MS SQL Server- Efficient Stored Procedures Issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, coding-efficiency

I have a lot of data that I need to insert then process based on the history of the data already in the database. This entails an initial `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` command and then a slew of queries, calculations, and subsequent `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` appending queries.

The actual processing part of my work is a general stored procedure but then I wrap it up with the unique initial `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` as a packaged stored procedure.

When I run a single day's stored procedure, it takes about 6 minutes. When I try to run multiple day's stored procedures in the same SSMS execution, it seems to take much longer than the 6 minutes per call. If I stop the stored procedure after a while, it seems like it actually has completed everything but was hung up at the end for some reason.

Are there any red flags in what I described that show I might be doing something inefficiently? I find that wrapping the packaged stored procedure in a `BEGIN ... END` clause helps but not always.

Sample code:

```
--STEP 3 DailyDataProcess

-summary query
-calculation query to join to summary query
-select into temp tables
-insert into select query
-more summary and calculation queries
-final insert into select query
-update yesterday's data where a certain event occured

--STEP 2 PackagedSP1

INSERT INTO InitialTable (col 1, col 2, todaysdate) 
VALUES (1, 2, 8/14/2017) 

EXECUTE DailyDataProcess

--STEP 1 MultiCall

BEGIN EXECUTE PackagedSP1 END
BEGIN EXECUTE PackagedSP2 END
BEGIN EXECUTE PackagedSP3 END
BEGIN EXECUTE PackagedSP4 END
```

Comment: The first red flag is that isn't valid SQL, and secondly, you  don't know for sure where it's getting caught up. You need to do some more investigation because what you've posted doesn't give any clues. You can use `sp_WhoIsActive` to observe it while it's running (as well as what it's waiting for). Or you can use SQL Profiler to observe it while it's running. Or you can sprinkle `RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT` into your sp's to spit out progress messages. Use one of these three methods to identify where it's actually waiting then come back with something specific.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid this is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid So I ran `sp_WhoIsActive` and called up the execution plan. It looks like it's doing a table scan on 2 smaller tables and 1 very large table (300mill rows) which are using up 100% of the operator cost and suspending the execution without killing it. I think I need to index that table but am not too knowledgeable on what to do exactly. Do you know of any good resources where I can look up what would be the best plan of attack on how to index? Maybe I can send you the execution plan?

Comment: Normally CTRL-L (query plan) suggests an index. Right click it to generate the index creation script on a new page. scans on smaller tables are normal and expected. Scans on large tables are bad but easily fixed with the right index. Luckily you have a performance issue which is simply fixed!

Comment: Again we cannot suggest an index because there is no detail in your question. Create the index that CTRL-L suggests and go from there

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for the help. Its looking like a server cache issue now rather than indexing. I'll have more info tonight. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's quite a vague comment. CPU cache? SAN cache? If you have very large table being table scanned, you can be almost certain that an index will improve it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid At the end of the day, the issue revolves around the stored procedure taking much longer to run than if I executed it myself. From what I'm reading, clearing the cache when moving from one SP call to the next should solve that but I'm running into issues with a block that I need to fix first.

Comment: That sounds more like parameter sniffing. This is much more easily fixed by using `WITH RECOMPILE`. Then you're not clearing the entire database cache

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Cool thanks! I'm tempted to just ignore the blocked table and create a new one. Where would `WITH RECOMPILE` go in the SQL, when I create the stored procedure or just when I'm calling them?

Comment: Your new table will probably have the same problem. Here's an example of using WITH RECOMPILE https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid So I created a new table and reran while including `WITH RECOMPILE`. It was no longer getting hung up on that table! If you want to post an answer saying to create an index and use `WITH RECOMPILE` I'll mark it correct!